# Snowflake pipe_usage_history: Question regarding Credits & Cost

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

(Submitting on behalf of a Snowflake User)

---

In Snowflake UI, I see that `pipe_usage_history` has a column for `credits_used`. Does this column include the credits for the event notifications, which are charged at 0.06 credits per 1000 notifications?

Please advise...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(According to Snowflake Sales Engineers)

You are correct in that the column does include the credits for recent notifications.  It is advised, though, that if you are seeing any sort of discrepancy, that you should file a support ticket to initiate a possible bug report.